# Kivy trigger on_release automatically different than on KV language

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have the following on my KV language:

```
TabbedPanelItem:
text: 'Item 2'
on_release: print('foo')
```

If I click on my tab item, I got a correct message (foo).

But if I try to call `on_release` method on my python code, it does not work. Like this:

```
else:
    tabbed_panel = self.parent.parent
    tabbed_panel.tab_list[1].on_release()
```

I am doing this, because if I call `tabbed_panel.switch_to(tabbed_panel.tab_list[1])`, it does not call `on_release` method of my tab item. 
What am I doing wrong? What I have to do, to fix it? Is there some other behavior like `on_switch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger an event of a Kivy widget, first check if such an even is available. If yes, then simply use [`dispatch`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.dispatch) to trigger it.

**Example:**

```
tabbed_panel.tab_list[1].dispatch('on_release')
```

`on_release` method means on release of a *touch* (from the widget's area), not on release of a `Screen` from `ScreenManager`. `switch_to` is just for changing one `Screen` for another.

Comment: you helping me again? =)
Thank you, it works perfectly!